# How to create a loopback camera through Android HAL?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, hal

1\ Regarding to Android Source Project hosted by source.android.com, Android supports [multi-camera](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/multi-camera) functionality. Also we have some information about how a [camera](https://source.android.com/devices/camera) driver really works in Android.

2\ As you know there is an old project called [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) that you can install and run on your Linux (it's simple if you have root access). For example you can also have fun with `ffmpeg` to stream a video as a dummy webcam device. ([v4l2virtualdevice_android](https://github.com/icefreedom/v4l2virtualdevice_android))

Qust\ What I'm really watching for is simple in logic and hard to develop. I want a solution that my Android application (that is provided as an APK) will be able to create a dummy camera and I can feed that from another source (not really important; maybe a video file). So user will be able to use original camera app, Instagram app (Live), etc ... to record the video.

I don't really know if it's necessary for device to be `root` or not. And if it's possible how can it be done using java or NDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you replace the system camera HAL. It's quite possible if you build a custom ROM. Having root access on a known device is essentially same as having your custom ROM. But this doesn't help if your APK is installed (with root access) on a different device, even if the changes are minimal. Sure you can prepare logic that will work on many devices, but each will require separate consideration and testing.

Comment: As you can see the project v4l2 Android provides some code written in C base. Can we implement those files as NDK in our project or not? / Which resources can I find for a fast tutorial to build a custom ROM for Android with those specifications? / Thank you

Comment: Start with https://abdullahyousafzaii.wordpress.com/2015/08/02/how-to-write-a-kernel-module-for-android/. Be careful to choose a device that runs kernel version compatible with https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.